# Get the lowest value in Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

The situation is rather complex, please be prepare,

this is the array outcome before filter

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pointText] => 1000pts
            [points] => 1000
            [redeemMode] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pointText] => 950pts
            [points] => 950
            [redeemMode] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pointText] => 800pts + Cash RM 200
            [points] => 800
            [redeemMode] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [pointText] => 500pts + Installment RM 100 (5% | 12 Months)
            [points] => 500
            [redeemMode] => 3
        )

)
```

I Need to check if the redeemMode has more than 1 same value, i will just show the lowest points in foreach result. In the above example redeemMode => 1 seem appear more than once, i don't want to show both points which have same redeemMode, i just want to show the lowest points. In this case, i would show points => 950 pts only. The rest of the redeemMode => 2 and 3 will remain as same.

this is the array outcome after filter

```
    Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [pointText] => 950pts
            [points] => 950
            [redeemMode] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pointText] => 800pts + Cash RM 200
            [points] => 800
            [redeemMode] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pointText] => 500pts + Installment RM 100 (5% | 12 Months)
            [points] => 500
            [redeemMode] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: did the data come from a db query? if so this could all be done there

Comment: Nope, the return data is from REST API.

Comment: since points is not an integer, how do yo know whats lowest?

Comment: thanks dude, you've reminded. i've added the integer value in the array. it can be called from the API.

Comment: Why not loop through every other value of the array, checking if it is the same, and then if it is, return the lower value?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 3):

Consider this. The items are put into an array that is keyed by the redeem mode. If that key already exists it checks which has the lowest points value to decide which one to keep.

```
$items = array(
    array(
        'pointText' => '1000pts',
        'points' => '1000',
        'redeemMode' => '1'
        ),
    array(
        'pointText' => '950pts',
        'points' => '950',
        'redeemMode' => '1'
        ),
    array(
        'pointText' => '800pts + Cash RM 200',
        'points' => '800',
        'redeemMode' => '2'
        ),
    array(
        'pointText' => '500pts + Installment RM 100 (5% | 12 Months)',
        'points' => '500',
        'redeemMode' => '3'
        ),
    );

$itemsByRedeemMode = array();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (isset($itemsByRedeemMode[$item['redeemMode']])) {
        if ($item['points'] < $itemsByRedeemMode[$item['redeemMode']]['points']) {
            $itemsByRedeemMode[$item['redeemMode']] = $item;
        }
    } else {
        $itemsByRedeemMode[$item['redeemMode']] = $item;
    }
}

print_r($itemsByRedeemMode);
```

Comment: thanks George! the filter seem working but. it doesn't choose the lowest value points. and i don't understand how's the code in foreach works too.

Comment: Sorry - that code wasn't exactly correct - have now edited. It creates a new array and loops through the original array and adds the items to the new array. When it adds items to the new array it uses the redeemMode value as the key value. The code inside the foreach loop checks to see if the current item has a smaller points value than the existing item at that position in the array. If it does it replaces the existing value at that position.

Comment: this make sense George. this is my first time encounter this kind of method. u r awesome!

Answer (score 0):

My colleague try to help out and this is his solution

```
    <?php
    $array = array(
        array
            (
                'pointText' => '1000pts',
                'points' => 1000,
                'redeemMode' => 1
            ),

        array
            (
                'pointText' => '950pts',
                'points' => 1050,
                'redeemMode' => 1
            ),

        array
            (
                'pointText' => '800pts + Cash RM 200',
                'points' => 800,
                'redeemMode' => 2
            ),
        array
            (
                'pointText' => '500pts + Installment RM 100 (5% | 12 Months)',
                'points' => 500,
                'redeemMode' => 3
            )
    );
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array as $data) {
        $isHas = 0;
        $mode = $data['redeemMode'];
        foreach ($result as $key=> $data1) {
            if ($data1['redeemMode'] == $mode) {
                if ($data['points'] < $data1['points']) {
                    unset($result[$key]);
                    array_push($result,$data);
                }
                $isHas = 1;
            }
        }
        if ($isHas == 0) {
            array_push($result,$data);
        }
    }
    print_r($result);
?>
```

its working! credit to my colleague!

Answer (score 0):

A little array reduction makes this pretty compact:

```
$array = array_reduce($array, function (array $result, array $item) {
    if (!isset($result[$item['redeemMode']]) || $item['points'] < $result[$item['redeemMode']]['points']) {
        $result[$item['redeemMode']] = $item;
    }
    return $result;
}, []);
```